# ASP.NET MVC Application crashing randomly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, production-environment

I created a MVC 2 Application to work as a RSS Feeder and deliver News Contents for a number of applications to consume.
Everything was doing fine until yesterday when suddenly my application started throwing a random error which doesn't tell me much of what's going on (or at least I don't understand it).
This error only occurs in Production and cannot be reproduced in staging or my local machine.

Here's the stack trace:

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper'.errorPath:/Android/Edition/2011-11-22/P1
>   HostIP:##.##.##.## at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage,
>   VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception
>   error, String queryStringOverride) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter
>   writer, Boolean preserveForm) at
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler,
>   TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass14.b*_11()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__4() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

This error only occurs sometimes and can throw at any action of any controller.
I would like to have found the reason in a specific action but it only throws sometimes and can throw for any action.

Comment: Can you tell us what /Android/Edition/2011-11-22/P1 is?

Comment: /Android/Edition/2011-11-22/P1 is just a root path which leads to an action called Edition. I displayed the stack trace when the error triggered in this action but it does trigger in all other actions as well.

Comment: MMmmm okay, not relevant then. Maybe this link can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862008/whats-the-cause-of-error-executing-child-request-for-handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such *byzantine* errors are hard to debug. The stack trace you're seeing does not help in diagnosing the error.

First, you should improve error logging. In your `global.asax`, create an implementation of the `Application_Error` hook that logs the exception *and all inner exceptions* to a file (I wouldn't log this to the database, because the db connection could be the culprit). Make sure that this code is solid: it should focus on these critical errors and not log every 404 page. Also, make sure that the logging code itself does not create any problems (it should be highly error tolerant).

The cause for this kind of problems is usually access to some kind of static variables. Out of all keywords, I believe `static` is by far the most dangerous one because it is so subtle.

Some common errors I've seen.

- **Caching** Someone wanted to be smart and cache some data in a static dictionary or so. Unfortunately, the locking code is flawed. An exception occurs only if the code for some user tries to add sth. to the cache, but it's already there:

  ```
  if(_dict.ContainsKey(cacheKey) == false)
  {
     // second thread adds data to the dictionary here
     _dict.Add(cacheKey, cacheData); // exception
  }
  ```

  This can also happen in a 3rd party library that uses caching or pooling. Access static variables with care.
- **Uncommon Code Paths** Something unusual happens that calls code that is not called very often, and that code is flawed. If you have testing with high code coverage, check the spots that are not covered by the tests.
- **DB Connection Lost** A socket reset on the db connection could lead to exceptions. Many database connection libraries / drivers fix this quickly (i.e. the next request will be fine). This is hard to handle; basically it shouldn't happen but there are many reasons why it could occur.

Comment: Your answer is quite informative and I will be investigating the matters you mentioned. Quite frankly, I do some caching for some actions in this application but that caching is not used for the opening actions of the application. Is it possible that when the app for some reason crashes will take a while to restart working normally? And to add up, I'm using an implementation of Application_Error in global.asax but I will improve it accordingly with your tips. Feedback later today.

Comment: Hehe, caching is fine of course -- but it's easy to add subtle bugs :) There's a big delay if the entire app has to restart, because the views are usually compiled on-the-fly. If it's a caching problem, maybe your cache is empty an now all data must be read again. Good luck.

Comment: I somehow got it to reproduce in local environment by spamming F5 on this page where the exception was throwing. I got it still in debug and on hold while I'm examining the variables. Do you got any tips that I could use to help investigate this problem? Also do you think that the fact I spammed refresh on the action could be part of this problem?

Comment: Yes. In a production environment, there are more requests, so there is a high chance that two threads will access a static variable at the same time. That does not usually happen in a single-session debug. If you keep hitting the local machine, you'll spawn up multiple threads as well. Using the debugger is tricky, because it's now multi-threaded so you can't step through your code. I'd suggest you enable the 'break on first-chance exception' option and try to find the error that way.

Comment: I will try to enable it and debug that way. Is it possible this exception is triggered by a request overflow to this action? There are no static variables being used/called in this particular action. I will get back at you once I find more.

Comment: Hm, as far as I know request queuing is handled on the IIS level so it shouldn't throw an exception in your code. Also, that queue is pretty long by default. Static access can be hidden in stuff like db access, logger access, some file access (e.g. auto-optimized js/css files), etc.

Comment: Well, I finally found the exception thanks to your tips. It's: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. The problem now is that the tips to fix this exception were telling me to enable MARS on my connectionString (which I did now) but still, after spamming loads and loads of requests, it eventually blew up again.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use `DataReader` very often and I don't know what 'MARS' is. I'd suggest you create a new question for the now known problem; this comment thread is growing a bit too long.

Answer (score 1):

This error tells you, that the true error is somewhere in some child action, that is action rendered by Html.RenderAction().

There is no such thing as "random" error - there has to be scenario where it happens, you just dont know it because the conditions vary maybe.

You should identify all your child actions, and test them with various inputs.. after you identify the problematic input set, try disabling child actions one by one and find the error this way.

Comment: random is a way of naming it when I ain't sure of what's throwing this error which, like I said, does happen for every Action of any Controller in my app. Sometimes it can spend hours without happening. A detail worth mentioning is that there's a page which I load with data from the database and the Action responsible receives no parameter. So it loads always the same way. This action throws this exception sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. To be true, it really rarely happens.

Comment: Again - the error is in some child action, called by Html.RenderAction() from your view or maybe even layout. This way it can seems that "every action can crash", but that is not true - your child action "included" in result of all actions can crash. Examine your child actions.

Comment: Rouen, I don't really have child actions, and I didn't even know they existed for MVC2. Any ideas?

Comment: I am pretty sure child action is behind this.. if it is not in your case, then i have no idea...